# Processing to P5 — How to convert?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to convert the following sketch to P5.js. Unfortunately, I am getting errors with several syntaxes including `PGraphics, beginDraw() and endDraw()`. My questions are:

What is the best way to convert Processing to P5 and vice-versa? And, what are the P5.js replacements for these problematic syntaxes?

```
PGraphics sourceImage;
PGraphics maskImage;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(512, 512);

  // create source
  sourceImage = createGraphics(512,512);
  sourceImage.beginDraw();
  sourceImage.fill(255,0,0);
  sourceImage.translate(width/2,height/2);
  sourceImage.rotate(PI/3);
  sourceImage.rect(0,0,100,500);
  sourceImage.endDraw();

  // create mask
  maskImage = createGraphics(512,512);
  maskImage.beginDraw();
  maskImage.triangle(30, 480, 256, 30, 480, 480);
  maskImage.endDraw();

  // apply mask
  sourceImage.mask(maskImage);
}

function draw() {
  // show masked source
  image(sourceImage, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Since Javascript is dynamically typed `PGraphics sourceImage;` doesn't make sense. There doesn't seem to be a p5.js object that exactly corresponds to a `PGraphics` object, though it seems that `CreateGraphics()` can be used to create a similar object. At a minimum, you should replace `PGraphics sourceImage;` by `var sourceImage;`

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to magically convert a script from Processing to P5.

Read [this tutorial about Processing transition to p5](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Processing-transition).

---

As @John Coleman says, variables must be created with `var`

```
var sourceImage;
var maskImage;
```

P5.Graphics works almost like in Processing. But you don't need `beginDraw` and  `endDraw`

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(512, 512);

  // create source
  sourceImage = createGraphics(512,512);
  sourceImage.fill(255,0,0);
  sourceImage.translate(width/2,height/2);
  sourceImage.rotate(PI/3);
  sourceImage.rect(0,0,100,500);

  // create mask
  maskImage = createGraphics(512,512);
  maskImage.fill(0, 0, 0);
  maskImage.triangle(30, 480, 256, 30, 480, 480);
```

Also, masks doesn't works on graphics. In P5, this is only for images. There is no simple way to convert graphic to images. So, I wrote a function.

```
  // apply mask
  sourceImage = graphicToImage(sourceImage);
  maskImage = graphicToImage(maskImage);
  sourceImage.mask(maskImage)
}

function graphicToImage(graphic){
  // create an image with the same size.
  img = createImage(graphic.width, graphic.height);
  // load graphic and img pixels into pixels array
  graphic.loadPixels();
  img.loadPixels();

  // copy pixels from graphic to img
  for (var i = 0; i < img.pixels.length; i++) {
    img.pixels[i] = graphic.pixels[i];
  }
  // update img's pixels from pixels array
  img.updatePixels();

  // return copied image
  return img;
}
```

There we are !

```
function draw() {
  // show masked source
  image(sourceImage, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Cdrom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046060/873165) is already excellent, but I'll add one piece of advice: you shouldn't try to convert code from one language to another line-by-line. Instead, you should take a step back and write down what the original program is doing, in English.

[Break the program down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and write out each of those steps in English. When you have that written down, you have an algorithm that you can implement in your target language.

In your case, your algorithm might look something like this:

- Create a source buffer graphics.
- Draw a scene to that buffer graphics. (This could be further broken down into smaller steps).
- Create a mask graphics.
- Draw a triangle to that mask graphics.
- Mask the source buffer graphics with the mask graphics.

Then you can take those individual steps and implement them using P5.js. Break each one down into even smaller steps that you can start googling, and go from there. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just the step you're stuck on. But the real lesson is that you should **not** be translating code line-by-line. Good luck.